# Convert text file to csv using shell script

Tags: bash, shell, csv, unix, export-to-csv

I have a file like this

```
InputFile.txt
JOB JOB_A
  Source C://files/InputFile
  Resource 0 AC
  User Guest
  ExitCode 0 Success
EndJob
JOB JOB_B
  Source C://files/
  Resource 1 AD
  User Current
  ExitCode 1 Fail
EndJob
JOB JOB_C
  Source C://files/Input/
  Resource 3 AE
  User Guest2
  ExitCode 0 Success
EndJob
```

I have to convert the above file to a csv file as below

[image]

How to convert it using shell scripting?

Comment: One would use _awk_ or _sed_ (string replaces).

Comment: CSV formats are textual. Please, never show plain text with images. They are not searchable, not copy-paste-able, much heavier than needed, they affect accessibility negatively and, in the case of your picture, it does not provide enough information because there are many variants of CSV (field separator, quoted fields or not...) Please copy-paste the text of your expected CSV file in your question and [format it properly](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting), instead.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used awk.
The separator is a tabulator because it's more common than a comma in the CSV format.
If you want a coma, you can simply change the `\t` -> `,`.

```
cat InputFile.txt | \
awk '
 BEGIN{print "Source\tResource\tUser\tExitCode"}
 /^JOB/{i=0}
 /^\s/{
    i++;
    match($0,/\s*[a-zA-Z]* /);
    a[i]=substr($0,RLENGTH+RPOS)}
 /^EndJob/{for(i=1;i<5;i++) printf "%s\t",a[i];print ""}'
```

- The first line `BEGIN` writes header.
- The second line matches `/JOB/` and only sets an iterator `i` as zero.
- The third line matches the blank on the start of a line and fills array `a` with values (it count on strict count and order of rows).
- The fourth part of the awk script matches `EndJob` and prints stored values.

Output:

| Source | Resource | User | ExitCode |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| C://files/InputFile | 0 AC | Guest | 0 Success |
| C://files/ | 1 AD | Current | 1 Fail |
| C://files/Input/ | 3 AE | Guest2 | 0 Success |

### Script using associative array:

You can change the script so that uses strict Source, Resource, User, and ExitCode values from $1 (first record) of lines, but it would be a little longer, and this input file doesn't need it.

```
cat InputFile.txt | \
awk '
 BEGIN{
  h[1]="Source";
  h[2]="Resource";
  h[3]="User";
  h[4]="ExitCode";
  for(i=1;i<5;i++) printf "%s\t",h[i];print ""}
 /^\s/{
    i++;
    match($0,/\s*[a-zA-Z]* /);
    a[$1]=substr($0,RLENGTH+RPOS)}
 /^EndJob/{for(i=1;i<5;i++) printf "%s\t",a[h[i]];print ""}'
```

Answer (score 1):

with sed ... dont know if the order in the InputFile.txt is always the same
as Source, Resource, User, ExitCode, but if it is

```
declare delimiter=";"
sed -Ez "s/[^\n]*(Source|Resource|User) ([^\n]*)\n/\2${delimiter}/g;s/[ \t]*ExitCode //g;s/[^\n]*JOB[^\n]*\n//gi;s/^/Source${delimiter}Resource${delimiter}User${delimiter}ExitCode\n/" < InputFile.txt > output.csv
```